# AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper on iOS set Bool values to 1 instead of true?

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk

So I have an odd one here. On iOS9.3 the AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper sets a Bool correctly to true or false in the DynamoDB table. However, running the same code on iOS9.2.1 it sets the same values to an Int of 0 or 1 instead. This breaks the whole db when I try and search for items in there based on these values.

Has any one encountered this?

I'm using Swift and the latest AWS SDK for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

On Model you have to use `NSNumber` for `Boolean`.

> For boolean values, you need to use NSNumber when you are defining the
>   model class. You can pass true and false as follows: `NSNumber(bool:
>   true)` and `NSNumber(bool: false)`. This is an inherent limitation of
>   the object mapping library the DynamoDB Object Mapper uses.

Source : [aws-sdk-ios on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/332)